# Access Auth in non blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the value of Auth::user()->id in the non blade file.

I tried to

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
echo Auth::user()->id;
?>
```

But i am always getting the

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found in 
D:\Development\chat\resources\views\layout\html\liked_you.php on line 4
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i get the value of `Auth::user()->id` in my file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Auth** class in **App\Http\Controllers** namespace. Auth facade exists in global namespace as an alias and in **Illuminate\Support\Facades**. So do one of:

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

with the first one being the preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting `Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth' not found in...line 3`

Comment: How are you rendering the view? It seems like you're not using Laravel to do that.

Comment: I am calling it directly from a php file.. i am not using `.blade`

Comment: That I see. But how are you executing that view? Is there Laravel involved? Like rendering that from the controller or sometehing.

Comment: No, i am not rendering through laravel, Actually i am using angularjs to render the view (the view was a regular .php file)

Comment: Then it won't work for you. In order to use Laravel Auth component you'd need to have Laravel instantiated so that Laravel classess, Auth component and session storage are available.

Comment: Then, is there any way to access it in m application ?

Comment: It is possible to use PHP views with Laravel (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views) if you decided to run your application with Laravel. You can also use Laravel components outside Laravel apps - see http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-components/ for examples. But why do you want to use Laravel Auth? I'm sure there are some PHP libraries that do the same but do not need so many dependencies

Comment: I wanted to do laravel auth, but i don't know how to include it in the top

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as well:

```
echo auth()->user()->id; // Equivalent to: \Auth::user()->id
```

Also this is possible:

```
echo app('auth')->user()->id;
```

You can use the helper functions anywhwre in your application.

Comment: But i am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function auth() in.....php on line 2`

Comment: Check the updated answer, `auth()` is a helper function but not sure if your version is right.

Comment: I am having only this in my file... is that ok ? `<?php
echo app('auth')->user()->id;
?>`

Comment: Stil i am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function app() in line no 2` error :(

Comment: I am rendering the pages by angularjs .. WIll that be a reason ?

Comment: This `echo app('auth')->user()->id;` is server side `PHP` code. You didn't clearyfy enough about your template.

Comment: No No, i understand that is server side php code.. I am able to do echo and all php codes there.. just including it from js..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83857/discussion-between-cable-raja-and-the-alpha).

Answer (score -1):

Use this script in the controller only:

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: This won't make any difference in a non-namespaced page like OP's.

Comment: when writing the two commands (use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; in the controller page ,error has been caused and when i remove the command (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;) the problem solved)